# ¿Enviando archivo con httpurlconnection la respuesta del servidor es bad request (400)?

Tags: android, http, fileupload

tengo un codigo que me funcionaba para enviar archivos al servidor, lo tengo usado en una app de ventas, pero quiero usarlo en otra app y no me da resultado.

```
String sourceFileUri = root.toString()+"/"+filename;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
        //File sourceFile = root;

        if (sourceFile.isFile()) {
            try {
                //String upLoadServerUri = "http://seminariosfupec.com/registroarchivosapp.php";
                String upLoadServerUri = "http://www.tucuenca.com/cspm/cargar_archivo.php";
                //URL url=new URL("http://"+server+"cargar_envio.php");
                //String upLoadServerUri = "http://"+server+"cargar_envio.php";
                Log.i(TAG, "enviarArchivo: ServerreponseCode  "+ upLoadServerUri);
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                //conn.setConnectTimeout (5000) ;

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE",
                        "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"bill\";filename=\""
                        + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math
                            .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                            bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file
                // data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                        + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn
                        .getResponseMessage();
                Log.i(TAG, "enviarArchivo: ServerreponseCode  "+ serverResponseCode);
                Log.i(TAG, "enviarArchivo: "+conn.getResponseMessage());
               // Toast.makeText(context, "ServerreponseCode"+serverResponseCode ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "enviarArchivo: Cargar completa");
                    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuffer sb= new StringBuffer("");
                    String line="";
                    while((line=in.readLine())!=null){
                        sb.append(line);
                        break;
                    }
                    resul=sb.toString();
                    in.close();
                   // showSuccessMessage("El servidor responde "+resul);

                }else if(serverResponseCode==400){
                    Log.i(TAG, "enviarArchivo: error 400 "+resul);
                   // showSuccessMessage("Error en el servidor");
                }
                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
```

El servidor me responde con codigo 400, bad request, la url esta activa y funcionando (http://www.tucuenca.com/cspm/cargar_archivo.php), estoy haciendo las pruebas en un huawei con android 9.

Espero sus comentarios.

ACTUALIZACION
Este es el log de httpurlconnection

```
07-02 13:11:50.575 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/Volley: 
 enviarArchivo: ServerreponseCode  
 http://www.tucuenca.com/cspm/cargar_archivo.php
 07-02 13:11:50.605 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/System.out: 
 (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
 07-02 13:11:50.605 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/System.out: 
 (HTTPLog)-Static: isShipBuild true
 07-02 13:11:50.605 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/System.out: 
 (HTTPLog)-Thread-2057-164130039: SmartBonding Enabling is false, SHIP_BUILD 
 is true, log to file is false, DBG is false
 07-02 13:11:50.605 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/System.out: 
 (HTTPLog)-Thread-2057-164130039: SMARTBONDING_FEATURE_ENABLED is false
 07-02 13:11:50.605 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/System.out: 
 (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
 07-02 13:11:50.605 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/System.out: 
 KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
 07-02 13:11:50.625 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/System.out: 
 KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
 07-02 13:11:50.905 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/Volley: 
 enviarArchivo: ServerreponseCode  400
07-02 13:11:50.905 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/Volley: 
enviarArchivo: Bad Request
07-02 13:11:50.905 18504-18558/com.semina.fupec.semifupec I/Volley: 
enviarArchivo: error 400 
07-02 13:11:54.079 18504-18504/com.semina.fupec.semifupec 
D/InputMethodManager: windowDismissed mLockisused = false
```

Comment: Puedes probar de ejecutarlo con un emulador con una versión inferior por ejemplo la 8? La versión 9 requiere algunos cambios para las peticiones http con la versión 8 debería funcionarte.

Comment: Ya lo hice con android 5 y dio el mismo resultado

Comment: @AlldesignWeb este problema no depende de la versión del sistema operativo Android sino de la petición.

Comment: No logro dar con la solución, veo que es un error del boundary, porque ya documente esa linea de codigo y el servidor me envio 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando obtienes   un [Response Code 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) que indica "Bad request", indica que el  servidor no puede o no procesará la petición debido a que uno o varios de los parámetros que configuras para realizar la petición no son adecuados, probablemente una sintaxis inadecuada.

En el caso de tu petición estos son los valores que envías:

```
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("bill", sourceFileUri);
```

pero **el problema es que no puede procesar este valor, revisa si el valor es aceptado y si el valor de `boundary` es correcto:**

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
```

incluso a modo de prueba, si eliminas esta propiedad seguramente obtendrías un [Response Code 200](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200) indicando que la solicitud tuvo éxito.

Comment: Es verdad documente la linea conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary); recibi un 200 desde el servidor pero el archivo no fue enviado, como sería el calculo del boundary, lo tengo asi     String lineEnd = "\r\n";  
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";